# Postgresql & Sqlalchemy fetching all query with excluding some column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm fetching the data from my postgresql database with sqlalchemy:

```
elif domain:
    query = universities.select().where(universities.c.domains == domain)
    return await database.fetch_one(query)
```

The code looks like this, somehow it includes `"id"`

```
{
  "id": 5788,
  "name": "American University of Middle East",
  "alpha_two_code": "KW",
  "country": "Kuwait",
  "web_pages": "http://www.aum.edu.kw/",
  "domains": "aum.edu.kw",
  "state_province": null
}
```

With execute i could do something like:

```
SELECT name, alpha_two_code, country, web_pages, domains, state_province
FROM universities
```

So on...

But how can i achieve that with sqlalchemy's query, i tried something like this

```
elif domain:
    query = universities.select().where(universities.c.domains == domain)
    return await database.fetch_one(query).prefix_with(universities.column_name != "id")
```

I knew it wont work but is there a way to fetch all the data except some value? in my case except id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#coretutorial-selecting

Selecting Specific Columns

If we’d like to more carefully control the columns which are placed in the COLUMNS clause of the select, we reference individual Column objects from our Table. These are available as named attributes off the c attribute of the Table object:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
>>> s = select([users.c.name, users.c.fullname])
sql
>>> result = conn.execute(s)
>>> for row in result:
...     print(row)
(u'jack', u'Jack Jones')
(u'wendy', u'Wendy Williams')
```

**UPDATE**. The other options are to use [exclude](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html?highlight=exclude#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.exclude_properties):

exclude_properties –

A list or set of string column names to be excluded from mapping.

Or:

Do what I do which is build a column list from the data dict, remove the column(s) from the list and pass that to the query

Comment: Hello Adrian, first of all thanks for your response, but it doesn't answers my question the thing i'm asking is the exactly the opposite, **how not** to select a spesific column, because writing down all the columns isn't productive, like i mentioned in the question i could achieve that with  `SELECT bla,bla,bla FROM bla  WHERE bla = %s` it will do the exactly same thing that you mentioned. but there is probably an easier way to exclude a spesific column.

Comment: Well there is this [exclude](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html?highlight=exclude#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.exclude_properties). Otherwise what I do is build a column list from the data dict, remove the column(s) from the list and pass that to the query.

Comment: adding  `'exclude_properties' : ['id']` to my table fixed it, thanks!